# How do the bonuses for investing in skill points scale?

Tags: hoard

Does anyone have a break down of what is actually gained per skill point invested in Hoard? I'm particularly interested in return on investment for damage and speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I e-mailed Big Sandwich Games and Tyler Sigman replied with a very helpful answer:

> Hi (Rapida),
>
> That's a great question. Here are the actual values.  Feel free to
>   distribute/post/etc., if you like.
>
> The numbers in the brackets correspond to the level of the upgrade.
>   E.g. m_flySpeed[1] is your starting state...level 1.  m_flySpeed[8] is
>   fully upgraded.
>
> Best regards,
>
> --Tyler
>
> ```
>            //DRAGON STATS
>            //SPEED
>                    //meters per second
>            m_flySpeed[0] = 0.0; //n/a array offset
>            m_flySpeed[1] = 25.00;
>            m_flySpeed[2] = 30.00;
>            m_flySpeed[3] = 35.00;
>            m_flySpeed[4] = 40.00;
>            m_flySpeed[5] = 45.00;
>            m_flySpeed[6] = 50.00;
>            m_flySpeed[7] = 53.00;
>            m_flySpeed[8] = 56.00;
>
>            //CARRY
>                    //units of gold
>            m_carry[0] = 0.0; //n/a array offset
>            m_carry[1] = 1000;
>            m_carry[2] = 1500;
>            m_carry[3] = 2000;
>            m_carry[4] = 2500;
>            m_carry[5] = 3000;
>            m_carry[6] = 3500;
>            m_carry[7] = 4000;
>            m_carry[8] = 4500;
>
>                    //units of gold per second
>            m_transfRate[0] = 0; //n/a array offset
>            m_transfRate[1] = 235;
>            m_transfRate[2] = 380;
>            m_transfRate[3] = 555;
>            m_transfRate[4] = 760;
>            m_transfRate[5] = 1015;
>            m_transfRate[6] = 1325;
>            m_transfRate[7] = 1725;
>            m_transfRate[8] = 2250;
>
>            //HEALTH
>                    //hit points
>            m_hp[0] = 1.0; //n/a array offset
>            m_hp[1] = 45.0;
>            m_hp[2] = 59.0;
>            m_hp[3] = 72.0;
>            m_hp[4] = 86.0;
>            m_hp[5] = 99.0;
>            m_hp[6] = 113.0;
>            m_hp[7] = 126.0;
>            m_hp[8] = 140.0;
>
>            //FIRE
>            //damage per second
>            m_fireDPS[0] = 0.0; //n/a array offset
>            m_fireDPS[1] = 45.0;
>            m_fireDPS[2] = 51.4;
>            m_fireDPS[3] = 57.9;
>            m_fireDPS[4] = 64.3;
>            m_fireDPS[5] = 70.7;
>            m_fireDPS[6] = 77.1;
>            m_fireDPS[7] = 83.6;
>            m_fireDPS[8] = 90.0;
>
>            //max breath duration in seconds
>            m_fireMaxDuration[0] = 0.0; //n/a array offset
>            m_fireMaxDuration[1] = 1.25; //1.25;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[2] = 1.57;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[3] = 1.89;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[4] = 2.21;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[5] = 2.54;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[6] = 2.86;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[7] = 3.18;
>            m_fireMaxDuration[8] = 3.50;
> ```

Comment: major props for actually emailing them